# "EnableBreezeQuery is not an attribute" error message

Tags: odata, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

After updating "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData" package to version 5.4.0 I get an error "EnableBreezeQuery is not an attribute" when applying the attribute on an Action of an ApiController.

Is there a Fix for that? I am using breeze 1.5.3 .

Thanks

Comment: Check that your project is actually referencing the new Breeze DLL. Sounds like you're hanging on to old code.

Comment: Ward thank you, you are right, is was a references issue but not with Breeze. After updating the nuget package I mention in my question, my reference to "System.Web.Http.OData" was broken and that was causing the error message on the Breeze attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a note to anyone facing this issue, re-installing `Breeze Server - for Web API 2.2` package solves this issue which as per the comment above contains the `*.OData.dll`